# Parabolic Mirror - proving focal length

Tags: linear-algebra, optics

I would like to prove that there is a focal length in the parabolic mirror. I wrote
script, but it's not working, can you guys see what I did wrong?

```
 y[x_] = -x^2
 x1 = x1
 dy1[x_] = D[y[x], x]
 (* Calculate tangent line to y[x] in x1 *)
 a = dy1[x1]
 (* Get the bias *)
 solveb = Solve[a*x1 + b - y[x1] == 0, b]
 (* tangent function *)
 tang[x_] = a*x + b
 (* normal vector to tang *)
 vec = {1, a}
(* Gram–Schmidt process *)
z = Normalize[vec]
vpp = {0, 1}
s = (vpp.z)*z
n = vpp - s
vpo = n - s
(* focal length is lying somewhere on the x-axis so*)
focaly  = Solve[ y[x1] + vpo[[2]] *t == 0, t]
t = t /. focaly[[1]]
focalx = x1 + vpo[[1]] * (t)
```

focalx shouldn't be x1 dependet, but as you can see it is. What I did wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proof but a motivating graphic:

```
f[t_] := {t, t^2};
g[t_] := {1, 2 t};
ln[t_, m_] := {f[t], {f[t][[1]], m}}
rot[p_, m_] := 
 RotationMatrix[-VectorAngle[g[p], {0, 1}]].(g[p] m) + f[p]
ppf[u_] := 
 ParametricPlot[{f[t], rot[u, t], rot[-u, t]}, {t, -2, 2}, 
  Epilog -> {Arrow[Reverse@ln[u, 4]], 
    Arrow[Reverse@ln[-u, 4]], {Red, PointSize[0.02], 
     Point[{0, 1/4}]}}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 4}}]
Manipulate[ppf[u], {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

`f` is the parabola. `ln` is the parametrization of the line of reflection based on angle to the tangent derived from derivative (`g`). You can tidy up. Perhaps it will motivate algebraic proof.